# How to get data from another android application

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I want to develope an application which extracts data from another application (the "whatsapp" application) when i am getting an incoming call.

How can I do it?
Maybe relevant guids will help :)
Thanks in advance!
Yogo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not possible, unless if the application makes it public, for instance, sharing  data via Intent or storing files in a public folder, e.g. in the SDCard.